# How to sanitize the readFileSync node js function input

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, checkmarx

I am trying to sanitize the input source `JSON` data in the below function. However, the Checkmarx tool still complains no matter where I add the `sanitizeObject()`. Appreciate  any pointers

```
const fs = require('fs')
const config = require('config')
var _require = require('jsdom'),
    JSDOM = _require.JSDOM;

var window = new JSDOM('').window;
var DOMPurify = createDOMPurify(window);


function sanitizeValue(value){
      return DOMPurify.sanitize(value);

}

function sanitizeObject(obj) {
  var sanitizedObject = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    sanitizedObject[key] = sanitizeValue(obj[key]);
  });
  return sanitizedObject;
};

const getMyData = () => {

 let myData = JSON.parse(sanitizeObject(fs.readFileSync('./my/dist/path/mydata.json')))

return myData
}
```

Checkmarx error: Stored-CSS error as follows

complains at `readFileSync`

The application's = embeds untrusted data in the generated output with send, at Xx of module.js. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

The attacker would be able to alter the returned web page by saving malicious data in a data-store ahead of time. The attacker's modified data is then read from the database by the = method with readFileSync, at line 11 of module.js. This untrusted data then flows through the code straight to the output web page, without sanitization.

This can enable a Stored Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack

Comment: I haven't heard of "checkmarx" before, it looks pretty bad for a static analysis tool. Is there a way to disable checkmarx for the file in question?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Comment: It's a commercial software and you pay money for it. You should ask the support.

Comment: Ok. jabaa, so does it mean that the sanitization is done correctly but the checkmark is not able to do its work correct?

Comment: does checkmarx complain if you `require` the json instead?

Comment: I'm guessing they have a specific way to demarcate the sanitisation function

Comment: ok. it did not complain about the require